Witness for NL Computation
For any NP language, we usually describe the language as having a polynomial time TM M such that for yes instance x you can find a witness such that M(x, w) accepts and for no instance M will not accept x no matter what the witness is.
I know that nondeterminism refers to transition in a state machine, so technically the witness w is read once only (you shouldn’t be allowed to rewind) but in the case of NP we can bypass this restriction by recording w locally and rewind all we want.
However, for NL it seems like you can’t do shouldn’t be allowed to rewind back to earlier parts of witness w as you can’t simulate the rewinding due to space constraints.
My question is, how is witness w usually modeled in an NL Turing Machine and how would the language be different if we are allowed to rewind witness in such TM?

What do you mean by "how is witness usually modeled in an NL Turing machine"? An NL Turing machine has no witnesses; it is just a nondeterministic Turing machine (with a read-only input tape and logarithmic-size work tapes). This, as you note, is equivalent to a deterministic logspace machine equipped with a read-once polynomial-size witness tape.

With an unrestricted polynomial-size witness tape, you get NP (easy exercise).

@EmilJeřábek yeah I get it now, I have heard something similar about how a Logspace TM with unlimited access to polysize witness is a lot stronger than NL. Thanks for confirming!
